# Prevent keyboard viewer from displaying

Tags: keyboard, input-source

Whenever I plug my MacBook into my external keyboard at work, the keyboard viewer window automatically opens up.

How do I prevent the keyboard viewer from automatically showing?

If possible, I'd like to keep the input sources menu bar item visible (the little American flag on the menu bar).

EDIT: i'm on mountain lion, i've got the viewer un-checked, and i'm still getting the viewer:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate checbox in the System Preferences... > Keyboard.

[image: Keyboard preferences screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

This problem hasn’t bothered me for some time, but I remember it used to occur (though I couldn’t pinpoint the exact circumstances). I have tried two different things:

1. After invoking the Keyboard Viewer, don’t close it by clicking the red close window button, but by clicking *Hide Keyboard Viewer* on the Input Menu in the menu bar.
2. If that doesn’t help, try deleting the Keyboard Viewer preference file: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.KeyboardViewer.plist`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences > Language & Text > Input Sources. Then uncheck Keyboard Viewer.